# Is this a caching issue? Drupal noob asking

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-9

I've got minimal Drupal experience and I've inherited a Drupal project.

Recently, after auto-deploying a change in a custom module, the site started showing intermittent error messages in some blocks.

Eventually, a cron job triggered a Certbot update and a restart of the web server - at which point nothing but error messages were showing.

**We got it fixed**, but I'm trying to understand what happened so it doesn't repeat, or I know how to resolve it if it does.

This was the error showing up in the logs:

```
Drupal\Component\Plugin\Exception\PluginNotFoundException";s:8:"@message";s:103:"The "language" plugin does not exist. Valid plugin IDs for Drupal\Core\TypedData\TypedDataManager are: ";s:9:"%function";s:58:"Drupal\Core\Plugin\DefaultPluginManager->doGetDefinition()";s:5:"%file";s:94:"/var/www/html/domain.com/web/core/lib/Drupal/Component/Plugin/Discovery/DiscoveryTrait.php";s:5:"%line";i:53;s:17:"@backtrace_string";s:5755:"#0 /var/www/html/domain.com/web/core/lib/Drupal/Component/Plugin/Discovery/DiscoveryCachedTrait.php(25): Drupal\Core\Plugin\DefaultPluginManager->doGetDefinition(Array, 'language', true)
#1 /var/www/html/domain.com/web/core/lib/Drupal/Core/TypedData/TypedDataManager.php(115): Drupal\Core\Plugin\DefaultPluginManager->getDefinition('language')
#2 /var/www/html/domain.com/web/core/lib/Drupal/Core/Plugin/Context/ContextDefinition.php(249): Drupal\Core\TypedData\TypedDataManager->createDataDefinition('language')
#3 /var/www/html/domain.com/web/core/lib/Drupal/Core/Plugin/Context/Context.php(103): Drupal\Core\Plugin\Context\ContextDefinition->getDataDefinition()
#4 /var/www/html/domain.com/web/core/lib/Drupal/Core/Plugin/Context/Context.php(54): Drupal\Core\Plugin\Context\Context->setContextValue(Object(Drupal\Core\Language\Language))
#5 /var/www/html/domain.com/web/core/lib/Drupal/Core/Language/ContextProvider/CurrentLanguageContext.php(55): Drupal\Core\Plugin\Context\Context->__construct(Object(Drupal\Core\Plugin\Context\ContextDefinition), Object(Drupal\Core\Language\Language))
#6 /var/www/html/domain.com/web/core/lib/Drupal/Core/Language/ContextProvider/CurrentLanguageContext.php(72): Drupal\Core\Language\ContextProvider\CurrentLanguageContext->getRuntimeContexts(Array)
#7 /var/www/html/domain.com/web/core/lib/Drupal/Core/Plugin/Context/LazyContextRepository.php(97): Drupal\Core\Language\ContextProvider\CurrentLanguageContext->getAvailableContexts()
#8 /var/www/html/domain.com/web/core/lib/Drupal/Core/ParamConverter/EntityConverter.php(141): Drupal\Core\Plugin\Context\LazyContextRepository->getAvailableContexts()
#9 /var/www/html/domain.com/web/core/lib/Drupal/Core/ParamConverter/ParamConverterManager.php(100): Drupal\Core\ParamConverter\EntityConverter->convert('331', Array, 'node', Array)
#10 /var/www/html/domain.com/web/core/lib/Drupal/Core/Routing/Enhancer/ParamConversionEnhancer.php(45): Drupal\Core\ParamConverter\ParamConverterManager->convert(Array)
#11 /var/www/html/domain.com/web/core/lib/Drupal/Core/Routing/Router.php(256): Drupal\Core\Routing\Enhancer\ParamConversionEnhancer->enhance(Array, Object(Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request))
#12 /var/www/html/domain.com/web/core/lib/Drupal/Core/Routing/Router.php(130): Drupal\Core\Routing\Router->applyRouteEnhancers(Array, Object(Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request))
#13 /var/www/html/domain.com/web/core/lib/Drupal/Core/Routing/AccessAwareRouter.php(93): Drupal\Core\Routing\Router->matchRequest(Object(Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request))
#14 /var/www/html/domain.com/vendor/symfony/http-kernel/EventListener/RouterListener.php(112): Drupal\Core\Routing\AccessAwareRouter->matchRequest(Object(Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request))
#15 [internal function]: Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\EventListener\RouterListener->onKernelRequest(Object(Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Event\RequestEvent), 'kernel.request', Object(Drupal\Component\EventDispatcher\ContainerAwareEventDispatcher))
#16 /var/www/html/domain.com/web/core/lib/Drupal/Component/EventDispatcher/ContainerAwareEventDispatcher.php(142): call_user_func(Array, Object(Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Event\RequestEvent), 'kernel.request', Object(Drupal\Component\EventDispatcher\ContainerAwareEventDispatcher))
#17 /var/www/html/domain.com/vendor/symfony/http-kernel/HttpKernel.php(145): Drupal\Component\EventDispatcher\ContainerAwareEventDispatcher->dispatch(Object(Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Event\RequestEvent), 'kernel.request')
#18 /var/www/html/domain.com/vendor/symfony/http-kernel/HttpKernel.php(81): Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\HttpKernel->handleRaw(Object(Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request), 1)
#19 /var/www/html/domain.com/web/core/lib/Drupal/Core/StackMiddleware/Session.php(58): Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\HttpKernel->handle(Object(Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request), 1, true)
#20 /var/www/html/domain.com/web/core/lib/Drupal/Core/StackMiddleware/KernelPreHandle.php(48): Drupal\Core\StackMiddleware\Session->handle(Object(Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request), 1, true)
#21 /var/www/html/domain.com/web/core/modules/page_cache/src/StackMiddleware/PageCache.php(191): Drupal\Core\StackMiddleware\KernelPreHandle->handle(Object(Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request), 1, true)
#22 /var/www/html/domain.com/web/core/modules/page_cache/src/StackMiddleware/PageCache.php(128): Drupal\page_cache\StackMiddleware\PageCache->fetch(Object(Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request), 1, true)
#23 /var/www/html/domain.com/web/core/modules/page_cache/src/StackMiddleware/PageCache.php(82): Drupal\page_cache\StackMiddleware\PageCache->lookup(Object(Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request), 1, true)
#24 /var/www/html/domain.com/web/core/lib/Drupal/Core/StackMiddleware/ReverseProxyMiddleware.php(48): Drupal\page_cache\StackMiddleware\PageCache->handle(Object(Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request), 1, true)
#25 /var/www/html/domain.com/web/core/lib/Drupal/Core/StackMiddleware/NegotiationMiddleware.php(51): Drupal\Core\StackMiddleware\ReverseProxyMiddleware->handle(Object(Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request), 1, true)
#26 /var/www/html/domain.com/vendor/stack/builder/src/Stack/StackedHttpKernel.php(23): Drupal\Core\StackMiddleware\NegotiationMiddleware->handle(Object(Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request), 1, true)
#27 /var/www/html/domain.com/web/core/lib/Drupal/Core/DrupalKernel.php(718): Stack\StackedHttpKernel->handle(Object(Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request), 1, true)
#28 /var/www/html/domain.com/web/index.php(19): Drupal\Core\DrupalKernel->handle(Object(Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request))
#29 {main}
```

I tried:

- Composer update and autoload dump
- Rolling back the code update
- Probably some other stuff; panic mode as a live site was down

What worked:

- Pointed the DB to the staging version (very recently updated from live)
- Did a `drush cache:rebuild`

So **what happened?** My theory is some kind of cache desync - perhaps an opcode cache of plugin functionality was out-of-date? As I said, Drupal noob.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What are you using to auto-deploy and what command are you executing during auto-deploy ?